# How to pass change data-toggle value on submit form

Tags: angularjs

Hi following is my code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="addForm.REFForm" role="form" ng-submit="saveInfo(currentPlayer.Player,playerinfo.StateLevel)" novalidate>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btnProfileDefault" ng-class="{'true':'active', 'false':''}[playerinfo.StateLevel]">
            <input type="radio" value="true" name="StateLevel" ng-model="playerinfo.StateLevel">
            Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btnProfileDefault" ng-class="{'true':'', 'false':'active'}[playerinfo.StateLevel]">
            <input type="radio" value ="false" name="StateLevel" ng-model="playerinfo.StateLevel">
            No
        </label>
     </div>
</form>
```

When someone click on the Yes I want to send that updated value of `playerinfo.StateLevel` to `SaveInfo` function but I am unable to do that `playerinfo.StateLevel` value is not updated on data toggle Is there any way.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you click Yes or No, The `saveInfo()` function in `ng-submit` won't be triggered. You should add ng-change like below or add a submit button.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btnProfileDefault" ng-class="{'true':'active', 'false':''}[playerinfo.StateLevel]">
        <input type="radio" value="true" name="StateLevel" ng-model="playerinfo.StateLevel" ng-change="clicked(currentPlayer.Player, playerinfo.StateLevel)"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btnProfileDefault" ng-class="{'true':'', 'false':'active'}[playerinfo.StateLevel]">
        <input type="radio" value="false" name="StateLevel" ng-model="playerinfo.StateLevel" ng-change="clicked(currentPlayer.Player, playerinfo.StateLevel)"> No
    </label>
</div>
```